# View through IBOutlet or manually created is nil after views hierarchy is loaded

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, storyboard, swift4

I am creating a **macOS** app on **Xcode 9.2** and i can't figure out why after the views hierarchy is created in `viewDidLoad()`, i can't use anymore the `IBOutlet` which is referencing the view in the **StoryBoard**.

I have found similar question, where they suggest to save the view that i want to update, as a variable, when i am in `viewDidLoad()` so i can use it later; if so what is the advantage of using an `IBOutlet`?

Can someone pls explain how to update in this case the content of the `PDFView` outside `viewDidLoad()` without getting nil?

**The AppDelegate**

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    // MARK: - Properties

    var filePath: URL?
    var result: Int?
    var fileObject: Data?

    // MARK: - Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var openFileMenuItem: NSMenuItem!

    // MARK: - App Life Cycle

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    // MARK: - My Functions

    @IBAction func openFile(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
        //Get the window of the app
        var window = NSApplication.shared.mainWindow!

        // Create NSOpenPanel and setting properties
        let panel = NSOpenPanel()
        panel.title = "Select file"
        panel.allowsMultipleSelection = false;
        panel.canChooseDirectories = false;
        panel.canCreateDirectories = false;
        panel.canChooseFiles = true;

        // Filtering file extension

        let fileTypes: [String] = ["pdf"]
        panel.allowedFileTypes = fileTypes

        // Showing OpenPanel to the user for selecting the file

        panel.beginSheetModal(for: window) {
            (result) in
            if result.rawValue == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {

                // Getting url of the file
                self.filePath = panel.urls[0]
                print(self.filePath)

                // Creating Data Object of the file for creating later the PDFDocument in the controller
                do {
                    if let fileData = self.filePath {
                        self.fileObject = try Data.init(contentsOf: self.filePath!)
                        print("\(self.fileObject) ")
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Error with file Data Object: \(error)")
                }

                // Getting the mainViewController 

                let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Main"), bundle: nil)
                let mainController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "mainViewControllerID")) as! MainViewController

                // Appdelegate call function of mainViewController to update the content of PDFView

                mainController.showPdfDocument(fileData: self.fileObject!)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The MainViewController:**

```
import Foundation
import Quartz

class MainViewController: NSViewController {

    // MARK: - Property

    var pdfdocument: PDFDocument?

    // MARK: - Outlets

    @IBOutlet var mainView: NSView!
    @IBOutlet var pdfView: PDFView!

    // MARK: - App Life Cycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    // MARK: - My Functions

    func showPdfDocument(fileData: Data) {
        print("appdelegate calling showPdfDocument on mainViewController " )
        pdfdocument = PDFDocument(data: fileData)
        pdfView.document = pdfdocument
    }
}
```

**The Error I Am Getting:**

[image: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value]

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Why not just update your pdfView in viewDidLoad?  I know you are asking how to do this without using viewDidLoad, but I don't understand why you want to.  Just set your pdfDocument variable, and then in viewDidLoad set your pdfView.document.

Comment: Because i need to wait that the user select the file using the openMenuItem and only after that update the content of the PDFView; I have successfully loaded a pdf when the app is starting and the view hierarchy is building during viewDidLoad(), but this is not the goal of this app. There are out there apps much more complicated than this, i can't believe there is not a simple way to do this. Even if i create the pdfview programmatically without storyboard, i always get nil outside viewDidLoad(). It seems that all the views disappears after viewDidLoad() is executed.

Comment: You are just thinking about it wrong.  It's not that the view disappears after viewDidLoad - it's the opposite.  You're trying to set this BEFORE viewDidLoad is called.  At least that's what's happening in your code sample and error message above.

Comment: They way most apps handle this is to create the viewController when the user selects the file (either programmatically or in Storyboard), pass the selected file in, and let the pdfViewController set up its own IBOutlets in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear.

Comment: ShowPdfDocument() is called after the user select the file which happen after NSWindow and all his subviews are loaded, and this happen after viewDidLoad() is finished ( from what i have read in the documentation). Also i have write some prints in the console to see that i am accessing pdfView after viewDidLoad() is executed . Notice that i have updated the code a few minutes later after creating the question ;). The viewController and pdfViewController you are mentioning are the same controller or two different controller?

Comment: I am noticing now representedObject var, where there is a comment saying '// Update the view, if already loaded.' Maybe this is the correct place to access the pdfView?

Comment: Look at the last 2 lines in your AppDelegate code sample.  That is the problem.  You instantiate the MainViewController and immediately set the PDF, but I guarantee viewDidLoad hasn't executed yet.

Comment: @creeperspeak what code are you looking at? the last line of the AppDelegate is 'mainController.showPdfDocument(fileData: self.fileObject!)' ; is in the showPdfDocument function of the mainViewController that i set the pdf file object.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  And that function calls `pdfView.document = ...`  That is where you are crashing, because your `pdfView` IBOutlet hasn't been instantiated yet.

Comment: @creeperspeak but the mainViewController that i am instantiating should be the same controller (has the same ID reference) that the viewDidLoad() instantiate with the view and the window from the Storyboard at the beginning when the app starts. I still don't understand why you say that viewdidload() is executed after the function showPdfDocument(); you mean that every time i instantiate a viewcontroller i should first call viewDidLoad() ??

Comment: also the IBOutlet shouldn't has been instantiated as you can see from the code? the IBOutlet is already referencing the view in the storyboard. You mean i should get the pdfView object through his reference id from storyboard? if yes, how can I do that?

Comment: First of all, it is NOT the same instance of the MainViewController as the one your app creates as the rootViewController.  You are instantiating a new one.  It might have the same storyboard ID, but it's a new instance of that viewController.  If you need to access the SAME instance you can say `window.rootViewController` to get a pointer to it.  You'll need to cast that as MainViewController to access your showPDFDocument function.

Comment: And just because you can reference an IBOutlet doesn't mean it has been set.  That doesn't happen until viewDidLoad is called, and you should NOT call viewDidLoad manually.  You let it happen on its own, but you write your code in such a way that your IBOutlets properties aren't modified until viewDidLoad is finished.

Comment: When I instantiate my MainViewController, when the viewDidLoad() will be called? automatically after the instantiation? If yes, how can i pass the fileData object to the viewDidLoad() of the MainViewController if i want to set the pdf in viewDidLoad()? to me it seems much more complicated this approach. There should be a simpler way to reuse the rootViewController to update the view. It's not much intelligent to create every time a new viewController to update the view.

Comment: I agree.  Read my comment.  You can access the rootViewController and update the view as much as you want.

Comment: Even if i can get the rootViewController, the IBOutlet of the pdfView will be accessible or i will get also nil there because the viewDidLoad() has been already executed? I will try this and let you know if it works even if i am not so confident because i have read that after viewDidLoad() is executed the view hierarchy is deleted and so the IBOutlet becomes nil.

Comment: You read wrong.  As long as your viewController stays in scope your view hierarchy remains, and your outlets remain.

Comment: also should i re-instantiate the IBOutlet of pdfView when i get the rootViewController? even if i didn't understand what did you mean by instantiate the IBOutlet of a view (i didn't find any method about that, only about the controller)

Comment: @creeperspeak also the rootViewController should be the one of the contentView of the window but shouldn't i need the reference of the MainViewController which is the one that contains the IBOutlet of the pdfView?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the current code in the `AppDelegate`. Basically i am using the `contentViewController` to update the `PDFView` but i don't know if this is a good practice because i should update the `PDFView` with its own controller and not with the one of the window.

**in the openFile function of the AppleDelegate:**

```
let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Main"), bundle: nil)
let mainViewController = NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.contentViewController as! MainViewController
mainViewController.showPdfDocument(fileData: self.fileObject!)
```

Reading from the Apple documentation at this link (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419615-contentviewcontroller) it says 'Directly assigning a contentView value clears out the root view controller.'. Should I programmatically assign my mainView to the contentView to automatically set my mainViewController as the initial controller?

I have also found that i can set my controller as the initial controller from IB as you can see form this image:

[image]

The ideal thing i want to do is to leave the contentViewController as the initial viewController (the default setting in IB) and then instantiate my mainViewController to update the pdfView. The problem is that with instantiation, the new viewController has everything to nil(IBOutlet, vars etc..). Is it the downcasting from contentViewController to mainViewController a good approach to achieve this task?